# How can I fix my SvelteKit script when using Google Translate?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

SvelteKit Script Doesn't work with Google Translate

I don't know what happen to my code when use google translate it doesn't work. I have function that show a timer.

when I choose another language (english default) the timer stop working.

I trying to console what in the element does, the log :

- English
  `00:32:15`
- Another Language
  `<font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">00:32:15</font></font>`

**Main script**

```
<script>
import EaxmTime from "../path-to-second-script"
let examtime = '23:00:00';
let arrTime = examtime.split(":");
let distance = arrTime[0] * 3600000 + arrTime[1] * 60000 + arrTime[2] * 1000;

function splitTime(data) {
    return [
        Math.floor((data % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
        Math.floor((data % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
        Math.floor((data % (1000 * 60)) / 1000),
    ];
}

let x = setInterval(function () {
    let timeSplit = splitTime(distance);
    examtime = timeSplit[0] + ":" + timeSplit[1] + ":" + timeSplit[2] + "";
    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
    }

    distance -= 1000;
}, 1000);
<script/>
<EaxmTime bind:examtime={examtime}/>
```

**Second Script**

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    export let examtime
    // trying console here while changing lang
    onMount(function(){
        console.log(document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML)
    });
</script>
<div class="flex">
        <img
        src="./stopwatch.png"
        alt="stopwatch"
        class="max-w-[25px] max-h-[25px] my-auto"
    />
        <span
            id="timer"
            class="timer-group xs:text-sm sm:text-base md:text-lg lg:text-xl"
            style="margin-left:5px; color:#e85347; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:5px;"
            >{examtime}</span
        >
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.